# Join only returning one row in getLoadSelect method rewrite

Tags: magento2, sql

I'm trying to load all of the associated entries to another table that has a foreign key

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $field = $this->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier(sprintf('%s.%s', $this->getMainTable(), $field));

    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from($this->getMainTable())->where($field . '=?', $value)
    ->join(
        ['second_table_alias' => 'second_table'],
        'first_table.entity_id = second_table_alias.entity_id'
    )
    ->group('second_table_alias.entity_id');

    return $select;
}
```

There are multiple rows that share that `entity_id` and if I switch between left join and join (inner join) it returns different results.

Is it possible to **get an array of all rows with that `entity_id` from the secondary table**? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The returned result needs to be fetched in order to retrieve the results:

```
$select = $entity->_getLoadSelect();
$data = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: `_getLoadSelect` is used by other methods (like load for example) and it should return an instance of a select, not the actual results.

Comment: @Marius true that I'm gonna edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

There only reason (I see) to load all the associated entities when the load select is executed is to be able to apply a filter on those loaded entities.
If you apply a filter inside the load select that should get only one record (or none) it should be OK.
So you can apply your filter directly in this method.
Take a look at the method from the [CMS module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page.php#L187)
If you just need the associated entities, I recommend you a separate method `afterLoad` for example, that will just query your secondary table and give you what you need.
Or better yet, have a method that retrieves the results when needed the first time, then stores them in a member variable.
This way you get lazy loading.